# Django : recursive use of "request.POST" caching?

Tags: python, django, recursion

Is there a **speed difference** between **Case 1** and **Case 2** ?

(*Assume that request.POST contains quite big data*)

---

**Case 1**

```
Class do_something():
     """
     Recursive use of "request.POST"
     """
     foo_1 = request.POST["foo"]
     foo_2 = request.POST["foo"]
     foo_3 = request.POST["foo"]
```

---

**Case 2**

```
Class do_something():
     """
     Save "request.POST" data as a local variable and reuse it repeatedly
     """
     foo = request.POST["foo"]
     foo_1 = foo
     foo_2 = foo
     foo_3 = foo
```

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, second case is faster but you can ignore this difference.

I ran these functions one million times on a quite big QueryDict:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> query_string = '&'.join('key%d=%s' % (i, 'xxx'*100*i) for i in range(100))
>>> len(query_string)
1485689
>>> POST = QueryDict(query_string)
>>> def func1():
...     foo_1 = POST['key1']
...     foo_2 = POST['key1']
...     foo_3 = POST['key1']
... 
>>> def func2():
...     foo = POST['key1']
...     foo_1 = foo
...     foo_2 = foo
...     foo_3 = foo
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(func1, number=1000000)
3.6945719718933105
>>> timeit.timeit(func2, number=1000000)
1.3247950077056885
```